# Round up to nearest power of 10

Tags: math, rounding, logarithm

I'm trying to figure out how to round up a number (greater than 0) to the nearest power of 10.

Examples:

```
roundUp(23.4) = 100
roundUp(2.34) = 10
roundUp(.234) = 1
roundUp(0.0234) = 0.1
roundUp(0.00234) = 0.01
```

For numbers greater than 1, I believe this works:

```
10^(ceil(log10(x)))
```

But for numbers between 0 and 1, I'm not sure how to arrive at the answer.

Comment: For me, your function works correctly even for numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: You're right, it does. A complete idiot moment for me.

Answer (score 5):

Oops. I didn't realize the function actually DOES work for numbers between 0 & 1. It was a brain fart that I saw a negative number for log10(x) and just assumed I couldn't take 10^ of that.

Carry on.